# left and right alignment rows inside Listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to implement interface like iphone sms:

[image: how to do]

Now I have chat listview with my custom ChatAdapter, incoming and outcoming messages inflates from different layouts:

outcoming layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/question_bubble"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="27dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/BlackColor"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

incoming layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:background="@drawable/answer_bubble"
    android:paddingLeft="27dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"    
    android:textColor="@color/BlackColor"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

I use "layout_gravity", but it doesnt work inside list view. Result:

[image: my interface]

How can I align question messages to right side?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a wrapper layout to your item layouts (for example a `LinearLayout`) that will have `layout_width="match_parent"` and `gravitiy="left"/"right"`, this will adjust the inner `Layout`/`TextView` to the right position.

In general it is highly recommended to not use `wrap_content` for items in a `ListView`, this makes the `ListView`'s `onMeasure` method to get repeatedly called and slow your app down.

Comment: thanks, its a good solution. also thanks for optimization hint.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this one:
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    **android:layout_width="fill_parent"**
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:gravity="right"**
```

Comment: hmm, its a correct way to. and it even more efficient, I suppose. But only for timestamp labels. Bubble images fill all row with this way

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on this problem also at the moment. Couldn't get it to work with the suggestions mentioned here. For me it worked only by using:`linearlayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);` and `setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);` programmatically after inflating a standard layout in the `getView` method of the adapter. These linearlayouts have a width of `wrap_content` and are child of linearlayout that has `match_parent` for width. Also don't forget to do this every time a view is being requested via `getView`, not only if `convertView==null`.

Answer (score 0):

if you encounter such problem make sure that your text layout is set in this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bubble_layout_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bubble_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble_right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxEms="12"
        android:text="Hi! new message"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

notice that the parent LinearLayout width is set to match_parent while others are set to wrap_content. 
this kept me up for hours.